# Syntax for multiple CASE statements and ISNULL() functions in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I've been stumped by this simple problem sent to me by a colleague.

While I understand what he's trying to do from a logical viewpoint, I am stuck on the syntax. It's really bugging me. I haven't really found anything like it on any documentation I've read. Below is his message with the most relevant chunk of code:

---

> Hey (TRose), here is a tough one to think on.  This is a mssql query and I have it
>   currently hiding ‘inactive’ parties when I select it as a parameter
>   but I left out ‘dismissed’ and need to add it in to the statement to
>   act just the same as ‘inactive’:

```
SELECT
CaseName = justice.dbo.fnFormatFullNameFMLSByNameID(cp.nameid),
CurrentKnownName = justice.dbo.fnFormatFullNameFMLSByPartyID(cp.partyid),
CasePartyAtty =  justice.dbo.fnCasePartyLeadAttorney(cp.caseid,cp.partyid),
cpc.casepartyconnid,
PartyActive = (select top 1  case isnull(inactive ,0)
when 0 then 'YES'
else 'NO'
end
from justice.dbo.CasePartyConnStat cps
where cps.CasePartyConnID = cpc.CasePartyConnID
order by cps.CasePartyConnStatID desc)
FROM  justice.dbo.ClkCaseHdr ct 
when 'OP' then '53OP'
when 'PA' then '53PA'
join justice.dbo.CaseAssignHist cah on cah.CaseAssignmentHistoryID = ct.CaseAssignmentHistoryIDCur
join justice.dbo.CaseParty cp on cp.caseid = ct.caseid
join justice.dbo.CasePartyConn cpc on cpc.CasePartyId = cp.casePartyid 
and BaseConnKy not in ('AT') 
WHERE ct.caseid = @CaseID
```

I'm decent at SQL but I simply don't know the answer to this. SQLFiddle is no help because I don't have schema information available. This is strictly syntax.

Any help I can get is appreciated.

Comment: Eww. Don't use "Top 1" like this. Rip the subquery out of your select and do the join properly.  Really the schema is needed here to better understand the question... but i think if you do the join properly you'll be able to put as many "case when"s in as you like.

Comment: Is there something missing from the "when 'OP' then '53OP'
when 'PA' then" -part? That can't be valid SQL

Comment: @NWest this is the way it was sent to me. Working in places with older code, you're bound to see some bad stuff. It's not up to me to change it radically, just help make it work. I agree with you though.

Comment: @JamesZ It's the way it was sent to me. I asked my source but didn't get an answer. You're right though; I just added some filler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this does not need a subquery:

```
PartyActive = (select top 1  case isnull(inactive ,0)
when 0 then 'YES'
else 'NO'
end
```

Just use and be explicit about the logic:

```
PartyActive = (case when inactive = 0 or inactive is null then 'YES'
                    else 'NO'
               end)
```

Depending on what the logic should really be ("and" or "or") you can do:

```
PartyActive = (case when inactive = 0 or inactive is null then 'YES'
                    when dismissed = 0 or dismissed is null then 'YES'
                    else 'NO'
               end)
```

This implements logic that says something is active if it is not inactive and not dismissed.